# Using ToggleButton's false .Value to remove the grey color on top when it is clicked

Tags: excel, vba, togglebutton

I'm trying to make a `ToggleButton` look always black but when clicked there's always this grey mask appearing on top (probably for the "clicked" effect) :

[image: Without the grey on top][image: With the grey on top]

I found that with the `false` `.Value` of the `ToggleButton` you can remove it but my problem is now that the userform I'm making appear is appearing again once closed. Is there a way to fix that ?
This is my sub for when you click the button :

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

    ToggleButton1.Value = False
    ToggleButton1.Caption = "Afficher l'interface"
    ToggleButton1.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ToggleButton1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    UF_Interface.Show 'Userform I want to show when you click the button

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the idea to have a Toggle-Button if you never want it in the "pressed" state? Why not use a simple button instead?

Comment: I think you are confused (or I am). When you lcikc the ToggleButton, the Value changes from false -> true. You are setting it to false again? Then you change caption and color and you open another form. If you want to not show the current form write before the show: me.hide.. Reminder: Take care you close the forms once leaving the UI_Interface form..

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'm not at work until monday but I think like @FunThomas said I should use a Simple Button instead of a Toggle-Button (dumb but yeah I should have done that since the start). My problem here is just esthetic and just for my personnal knowledge so thanks for your answers again! I'll keep you updated.

Comment: So I tested stuff and the normal button was definitely what I was looking for even if I can't change the back/fill color of the button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With the help of *[@karma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7756251/karma)*** I modified my code this way (since I couldn't change the color of a "normal" `Button` even though I wanted it's way of working) :

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    With ToggleButton1
        If .Value = True Then
            .Caption = "Afficher l'interface"
            .BackColor = vbBlack
            .Value = False
            UF_Interface.Show 'Userform I wanted to show
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest, if you want to use the ToggleButton,
maybe it's better making a two condition (if true then what, if false then what), 
such as the image below :

[image]

So in the image above, if true then open the other UF - if false then close that UF.

Below is the code in the UF where the ToggleButton reside :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ToggleButton1
        .Caption = "OPEN UF_Interface"
        .BackColor = vbYellow
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
With ToggleButton1
    If .Value = True Then
        .Caption = "CLOSE UF_Interface"
        .BackColor = vbGreen
        UF_Interface.Show vbModeless
    Else
        .Caption = "OPEN UF_Interface"
        .BackColor = vbYellow
        Unload UF_Interface
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Both userforms (UF_Interface and the one with the toggle button) must be shown in `vbModeless` state. So you need to make another sub in regular module, something like below :

```
Sub OpenFormWithToggleButton()
FormWithToggleButton.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for (I tried to replicate a normal button with a toggle button which is weird) but your answer contains a lot of useful information that took me where I wanted. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question !